# How can I expose a vampire?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've found a vampire in my fortress; but I don't want to kill him, as might turn out to be useful down the road.

What I *would* like, however, is to know his real identity! Is there any way in which I can force him to expose his real identity without killing him?

Comment: Do you want to know the vampire's true name to look for it in the histories/legends, or you want to identify the particular dwarf that is a vampire?

Comment: I want him to reveal and use his true name. I know who he is alread, and I even know his true name, but I want him to use it.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do that. While you may know who he really is, your dwarves don't, and he prefers it to stay that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Vampire), Dwarf Therapist will show his original name, which means comparing the unit list in DF to the list in Dwarf Therapist and eliminating all dwarves that appear in both. The last name in each list will show the alias in DF and the real name in Dwarf Therapist.

Alternatively, you can make a copy of the save, enter Legends mode, and then look up a dwarf that was killed by your vampire. It should say "in the Year N, Dwarf X was drained of all blood by Vampire Y".

Comment: Begrudgingly accepting this as truth. :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cursed my current game! Just found someone drained of all blood last Granite.